# extract data from the child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

I have several BUs that are children of a sabe BU. I am trying to extract data with the python FuelSDK by creating a client id and a client secret. The thing is that I can only extract data from the main BU that I created the API.

Is there any way to extract data from the other BUs (childs) without creating an client secret and a client id for every child BU?

[edit]
I tried to pass the accountId through the Client obj as shown below:

```
myClient = ET_Client.ET_Client(
False, False,
{
    'clientid': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'clientsecret': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'defaultwsdl': 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl',
    'authenticationurl': 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/',
    'baseapiurl': 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/',
    'soapendpoint': 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx',
    'wsdl_file_local_loc': r'(...)\etframework.wsdl.xml',
    'useOAuth2Authentication': 'True',
    'accountId': 'xxxxxxxx', #HERE I ADDED THE CHILD ACCOUNT ID
    'scope': 'offline documents_and_images_read documents_and_images_write saved_content_read saved_content_write automations_execute automations_read automations_write journeys_execute journeys_read journeys_write email_read email_send email_write push_read push_send push_write sms_read sms_send sms_write social_post social_publish social_read social_write web_publish web_read web_write audiences_read audiences_write list_and_subscribers_read list_and_subscribers_write data_extensions_read data_extensions_write file_locations_read file_locations_write tracking_events_read calendar_read calendar_write campaign_read campaign_write accounts_read accounts_write users_read users_write webhooks_read webhooks_write workflows_write approvals_write tags_write approvals_read tags_read workflows_read ott_chat_messaging_read ott_chat_messaging_send ott_channels_read ott_channels_write marketing_cloud_connect_read marketing_cloud_connect_write marketing_cloud_connect_send event_notification_callback_create event_notification_callback_read event_notification_callback_update event_notification_callback_delete event_notification_subscription_create event_notification_subscription_read event_notification_subscription_update event_notification_subscription_delete tracking_events_write',
    'applicationType': 'server',
    'redirectURI': '<REDIRECT_URI_FOR_PUBLIC/WEB_APP>',   
    'authorizationCode': '<AUTHORIZATION_CODE_FOR_PUBLIC/WEB_APP>'
})
```

And then a try to retrieve email data by the code below:

```
email = ET_Client.ET_Email()
email.auth_stub = myClient
email.props = ['ID', 'Client.ID','Name']
results = email.get()
print(results.status)
print(results.results)
```

The issue this time is that the results return an empty list, as shown below:

```
True
[]
```

So, this is the scenario: if I pass an empty accountId to the Client, the API returns me some data of the father BU, as expected. But if I pass a child accountId, it returns me an empty list although the "true" status.

What am I doing wrong this time?

Comment: the oAuth 2.0 token calls allows you to pass account_id to operate in the context of different MID. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm

Comment: hi EazyE. I tried to pass to accountId through the FuelSDK Client parameters (ET_Client.ET_Client(...)), using the oAuth2.0 'true' value. It returns a response but the response is always an empty list ([ ]). Any clue of what am I doing wrong??

Comment: I would suggest using postman to make your call based on the help doc then compare it to the json the sdk is making and compare

Comment: I am sorry I am so noob, but don't know how to work with SOAP directly... I am using the FuelSDK that it's easier... :'(